# rand() gives back higher int than my max c++

Tags: c++, random

So I hope I am not asking something stupid.

I want my program to pause for a random amount of ms going from 2000 to 5999 when a button is clicked so here is are the lines :

```
void ExpNatDlg::OnBnClickedBack()
{
   int delayRand;
   delayRand = (int)rand() % 6000 + 2000;
   Sleep(delayRand);
}
```

To check the delays I get, I print them on a file, and I don't know why, I sometimes get delays higher than 7000 ms...

I don't know what I'm missing ! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Getting delays higher than 7000 is possible as 8000 is your maximum.

Comment: Are you using c++11? If so you should use the newer random number library functions.

Comment: I thought the form `%n + m` meant that m was the minimum and  n the maximum... isn't it ? No I'm not using c++11

Comment: `rand()` returns an `int` result. The cast to `int` is superfluous.

Answer (score 5):

That's a simple question of mathematics. rand () % 6000 gives a result from 0 to 5999. Adding 2000 gives a result from 2000 to 7999.

Comment: Also, sleep() is not guaranteed to be that accurate. If you tell it to sleep for 7000ms, it will sleep for *at least* that, and likely more if the machine is running lots of other processes.

Comment: Do you know an alternative to sleep() that's more accurate ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `(int)rand() % 6000` will be anywhere up to 5999 so when you add 2000 you will go over the threshold.
To get the min and max of 2000 and 6000 you need to have `(int)rand() % 4000 + 2000`. This is because the random number will be generated in the range 0 to 3999 and then adding 2000 will give the range 2000 to 5999.

If you have c++11 available to you you could write the code like this:

```
///init for RNG
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine generator;
generator.seed( rd() );

//using the RNG
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,6000);
Sleep(distribution(generator));
```

The benefits here are that the random numbers will be of a higher quality and the intent of your code is clearer.

Comment: `(int)rand() % 4000` gives you numbers in the range 0 to 3999, not 0 to 4000. `(int)rand() % 4000 + 2000` then gives numbers in the range 2000 to 5999.